# Same application name on multiple IIS sites

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We're majorly redesigning our website, in terms of both aesthetics and architecture.  In order to avoid locking up the application against updates during this redesign, we'd like to redesign one module at a time and just pass users between the old and new sites as needed.  However, we have a variety of session information, including their logins, that we need to preserve throughout this shuttling.

If we setup two different webroot folders with ColdFusion files (one for the old and one for the new) each with its own IIS site, but setup the Application.cfc files in both to use the same application name, will the session and application scopes be preserved as users move back and forth between the two sites?  Will this cause any unexpected issues?

We are using ColdFusion 9.

Comment: Passing users back and forth between sites sounds like you are asking for trouble.  If you want to upgrade in phases, just do so.  If possible, make your changes during quiet times.

Comment: You might just bite the bullet and lock it down against updates. I've been through this process a few times. We rebuilt one module using a new architecture, but made sure to skin it so that we could easily swap out the look & feel. Once the new module went live, we started a project to convert the rest of the application (13 modules), based on the architecture of the first. New features were only added in the new code base and only bugs were fixed in the old. We went live with a new site a year later, no bugs, new features and an easy to update architecture.

Comment: Unfortunately, locking the system down is not an option as part of our business structure is paid upgrades.  I'd prefer to just upgrade in phases, but the team preference is for a new repository to start completely from scratch, so I'm trying to see what we can do to make that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this will work, as Dan has suggested, it's not a great idea. For one thing you will have no ability to change anything in the application scope on site A without affecting site B. This can introduce head-scratching bugs. Consider DSN names which are often in the application scope. Unless you are using the exact same DSN for both sites, whichever site is first initialized is going to dictate which DSN is used - so you basically have to live with the exact same application scopes.

Still, it can be done.  See this post for a plain example that might be helpful.

[Application Variables on ICE](http://mkruger.cfwebtools.com/index.cfm?mode=alias&alias=application.variables)  - ColdFusion Muse

Comment: Thank you.  The duplicated application scopes is actually what we want; they are to be two skins of the same application in a way.  I'll review the link you sent shortly.